# display a firebase timestamp in relative format using moment & react

Tags: momentjs

I'm trying to display a timestamp from firebase in a relative format.

Within my firebase collection I have:

```
author (string):         lechnerio
comment (string):        Test Comment is here!
createdAt (timestamp):   22 November 2022 at 13:47:06 UTC+1
```

and I'd like to display the timestamp in a realtive way, e.g.: 31 minutes ago

```
{author} schreibt am 
{moment(new Date(createdAt.nanoseconds), "YYYYMMDD").fromNow()}:
{comment}
```

What I'm getting back with the exact same values from above:

```
lechnerio schreibt am 53 years ago:
Test comment is here!
```

when just using `new Date(createdAt)` instead an invalid Date get's returned. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my issue.

```
{moment(createdAt.seconds * 1000).fromNow()}
```

In addition to the issue I was also struggling to convert english localisation to german, so "5 minutes ago" are supposed to be "vor 5 Minuten".

```
import moment from 'moment'
import localization from 'moment/locale/de'

moment.updateLocale("de", localization)

{moment(createdAt.seconds * 1000).fromNow()}
```